# Recursive functions in winning number

Tags: c++

I need to make a code that checks if parameter r is a winner.

```
int is_winner(const float r){

}
```

Comment: 1) why "recursive" in subject? 2) Try to write pseudo-code when is_winner shall do - then show us what have you tried so far to write it in C++ and what is the problem.

Comment: Why have you deleted all/most of your question's text? The way it is now, it makes no sense at all and you risk it getting closed because of "needs detail or clarity".

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following.

```
if (r <= max_winner && r => 0) {
  if (/* simple criterion */) { // i.e. whole game even
    return true;
  } else if ( /* recursive call */ ){ // recursion, i.e. r/2 is winner and r*r is winner
    return true;
  }
}
```

Note that I assume (for sake of simplicity) that the output of your function should be a boolean variable, since the function is called `is_winner`, where we just want to check if it is true or false.

Try to fill in the conditions on your own. Note, that there are functions like `std::floor`, `std::ceil`. Also be aware of conversion from `float` or `double` to `integer`; e.g. check the beahviour of

```
float r   = 2.7189;
int r_int = r;
```

Comment: So i try to do like this but it returns me nothing    ```int is_winner(const float r){
if ((r >= 0.0f  && (r <= max_winner)))
    {
        if ( fmod(r,2) == 0.0f )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (is_winner(r/2.f) && is_winner(r*r) )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}```

Comment: As I mentioned, the output of your function shouldn't be an `int` but a `bool`. In addition, it is asked that the whole of a winning number must be even, thus `fmod` is the wrong function, see [here](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/)

Comment: The function looks good. You can replace the random input with an array of test input and add prints in the function to help pinpoint the problem

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not giving code because I think this is an exercise that you should make yourself)

In this particular exercise, it is harder to understand what the required test actually is than to implement it after a lesson on recursive functions.

Basically, if the number is within the range and the integer part of the number is not even, check its half and its square until one of them goes out of limit or is even by calling is_winner() for both from within is_winner() and pass the result back (both should be winners) until you know that the given number is a winner or not.

I would print results in the function to see what is going on.

I guess, since 0 is part of the range, half is always a winner if the number is within the range.